# How can I read in a .gsheet file as a text file?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to programmatically access information in google sheet files on Google Colab, but because I'm working in a shared drive, the usual method of just giving the sheet name doesn't work (it only looks in my personal drive; this is a known bug.)

From the command line on one computer (Mac 10.13.6 High Sierra, Python 3.8.5), if I type

```
more exp4.gsheet
```

I see what looks like a python dictionary which includes the full url and doc_id for the sheet. I want to extract that dictionary so I can open the gsheet using its doc_id. I can also open the file using

```
f = open("exp4.gsheet","r")
f.readline()
```

And I get that same string.

However, when I switch into a Colab notebook, or onto my work computer (Mac 10.15.7 Catalina, Python 3.8.8), I get "exp4.gsheet: Operation not supported" on the command line and the following error from python.

```
>>> f = open("exp4.gsheet",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 45] Operation not supported: 'exp4.gsheet'
```

Does anybody know a workaround for this, or some other way to load a gsheet if I just give it a file path within drive? Thanks

Comment: if it looks like dictionary then maybe you have it as JSON data. Or maybe `gsheet` keep data and all information as JSON data. And you could try module `json` to convert it to python dictionary. But it may need also other work to extract interesting data. Maybe you could Google tools to export `gsheet` to `csv` file.

Comment: Yes, your first comment is basically is what I want to do - the problem is that I can't read the file in as a string in order to convert it to json. I'll convert to a csv as a last resort, but because there are multiple people contributing to the same sheet on this research project, it's a last resort